# template specialization based on const-qualified instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Suppose I have a templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        A(T& val) : m_val{val} {}

        T& val() { return m_val; }
        const T& val() const { return m_val; }

        //etc...
    private:
    T& m_val;
};
```

Can I have template specialization which is different for lines (1) and (2):

```
    int a = 5;
    A<int> x {a}; //(1)
    const A<int> y {a}; //(2)

    const int b = 10;
    const A<int> z {b}; //error: binding reference of type ‘int&’ to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers
```

Basically, in the `const` case I want to declare the underlying `m_val` as `const T& m_val;` because I've instantiated my wrapper class as `const` and I want to signify that the internal reference should also be `const` in this case.

Is this possible? I've tried several solutions and the only one that seem to work is to explicitly add `const` to the template argument like this: `const A<const int> z {b};`
Is it possible to avoid this inner const-qualifier?

EDIT: Changed the member variable to be a reference to show how const-ness can cause trouble for the compiler in this situation.

EDIT2: Removed the default constructor to simplify the problem.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: You don't need m_val to be constant. Because it is private, the only way to access it is through member functions, and you CAN control which functions will be called for const/non-const objects.

Comment: the thing you want would make `A<int> x; const A<int> y=x;` an error.

Comment: @BennyK I've updated my sample code to make a point of why I need the internals to be const. Suppose the internal member is a reference. Then we cannot take a const-qualified argument in the constructor because the member itself is non-const reference. But then we want the wrapper to be ```const``` and to pass ```const int&``` to the constructor. Which is impossible if the internal reference is not const.

Comment: In this case you'll have to us `A<const int>` explicitly. As @appleapple mentioned, this will make the class incompetible with non-const versions as it will be a completely different class.
You can avoid the "outer" `const` though, by using `auto`.

Comment: I've realized that what I need is a way to specialize the template based on the const-qualification of ```this```. If ```this``` is const, use one representation. If it is not, then use another.

Comment: do you realize `A<const int>` and `const A<const int>` (and `const A<int>`) has different meaning in `c++`?

Comment: @appleapple Yes, I want to make the compiler treat ```const A<int>``` as it were ```const A<const int>``` and leave ```A<int>``` unmodified.

Comment: well, I'm more interesting in why you cannot use `A<const int>`? you don't really need to use `const A<const int>` afaict from your code.

Comment: @appleapple I guess I'll be using the A<const int> version. It's not a big deal, I was just wondering why the compiler cannot deduce const-ness of the type of my members since the class instantiation itself is const. But I think I'm messing up two concepts here: const-ness of access and const-ness of instantiation.
Anyway, in C++17 the template argument type can be deduced by the compiler, so I can just write ```const int p = 5; A x {p}``` and ```x``` will be correctly deduced to ```A<const int>```.

Comment: glad you solve the question :)